# Aircraft identification

Tags: aircraft, world-war-two, identification

I am trying to identify the aircraft in the picture here.  I know it is a U.S. Army Air Corps training aircraft from World War II, and I'm guessing its an AT-6.  But I can't find a comparable photo that would show the same equipment that this photo shows.  Can anyone help?[image]

Comment: In the future you can search by image with Google. https://images.google.com/imghp?hl=en&gws_rd=ssl Just drag and drop stright into the search area. Pretty amazing. Here's a video by Google on how it works. http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html Good luck.

Comment: If you don't end up with an answer here, try asking with the [aircraft-identification](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/) tag on aviation.SE

Answer (score 14):

Looks a bit like a [Vultee BT-13 Valiant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vultee_BT-13_Valiant)

[image]

Comment: Looked around a bit at some other trainers for comparison, and I think you are right. Added a photo from its Wikipedia page. Notice the similarity in gear shape and placement, exhaust shape and placement, top antenna, and even paint job.

Comment: @T.E.D. Agreed on the other points but the paint job doesn't tell you a whole lot. Lots of USAF planes were varnished aluminium and it's very common to paint the top of the nose in front of the cockpit black, even today, to reduce glare for the pilot.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - The basic idea may have been common, but the *implementation* of it is still fairly disctictive. Compare with [this picture of T6-As](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_American_T-6_Texan#mediaviewer/File:AT-6C_Texans_in_flight_1943.jpg). Yes, the top of the nose is painted black, but it seems to start a bit higher (perhaps because the cockpit does), and the rest of the nose is painted army beige.